# Getting variables inside of another file

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, es6-class

Is it possible to access another variable from another file?
e.g. `firstFile`:

```
export default class myClass {
  constructor({name, price}) {
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
  }
}
```

in a separate file, I'm doing:

```
new VendingMachineItem({ name: "Cheese Puffs", price: 3 }),
new VendingMachineItem({ name: "Can of Soda", price: 1.75 })
```

So that it would run the constructor now in the other file I want to access `this.price` and `this.name`.

I'm currently importing it in this file but not sure on what to do...

Comment: You already gave the answer yourself. You have to export the variable in the source file (`export default...` works) and import it another (`import xx from 'src/path'`). Just make sure your environment supports your syntax (es6 export/import vs. commonjs `module.exports/require`).

Comment: Why do you pass a name and price as an object to the constructor? Instead of just passing them as two separate arguments? Is this a JavaScript trend I don't know about? :) And if you're going to pass a single object there, and just deconstruct it and initialize equally named properties of the object you're creating, why not just use `Object.assign`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An imported class behaves like you've defined the class right in the file, where you use it.

So, this:

```js
class Foo{ /*...*/ }

new Foo()
```

is equivalent to this:

```js
//foo.js
export default class Foo{ /*...*/ }
```

```js
//bar.js
import Foo from './foo.js'

new Foo()
```

So, use your class normally after you've imported it.

---

The `this` inside the class constructor refers to the newly created object.

So, you define `name` and `price` on the object, **that got returned from the constructor!**

Therefore just use the return value of the constructor:

```js
const newObject = new VendingMachineItem({ name: "Cheese Puffs", price: 3 })
console.log(newObject.name)  //Cheese Puffs
console.log(newObject.price) //3
```